# How to Return QuickBooks Report Results to WPF DataGrid Items?

Tags: c#, wpf, quickbooks, qbfc

I'm querying QuickBooks Desktop for transactions within a specific date range.  I'm using boilerplate, or what seems to be, code to assign the report data to a Transaction class and adding the properties of the Transaction class to a WPF DataGrid for review by the end user.

My AllItemsDataGrid is instantiated inside the user control from the XAML below:

```
<DataGrid Name="AllItemsDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" Loaded="EntriesDataGrid_OnLoaded">

</DataGrid>
```

I create the report request, response, a report return and populate transactions into the DataGrid as follows:

```
private void EntriesDataGrid_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (WalkReportRet != null)
            {

                var transactions = new List<Transaction>();

                var transaction = new Transaction
                {
                    TxnType = transaction.TxnType.ToString(),
                    TxnNumber = transaction.TxnNumber.ToString(),
                    TxnDate = transaction.TxnDate.Date(),
                    TxnName = transaction.TxnName.ToString(),
                    GLAccount = transaction.GLAccount.ToString(),
                    TxnAmount = transaction.TxnAmount.ToString(),
                    TxnCleared = transaction.TxnCleared.ToString(),
                    TxnSplit = transaction.TxnSplit.ToString()
                };
            }

            return;
            AllItemsDataGrid.ItemsSource = transactions;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
    }

    public void RunQuery(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool sessionBegun = false;
        bool connectionOpen = false;
        QBSessionManager sessionManager = null;

        try
        {
            //Create Session Manager
            sessionManager = new QBSessionManager();

            //Create the request to obtain the Profit and Loss Summary Report
            IMsgSetRequest requestMsgSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 13, 0);
            requestMsgSet.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue;

            BuildGeneralDetailReportQueryRq(requestMsgSet);

            //Connect to QB Desktop and begin a Session
            sessionManager.OpenConnection(
                @"C:\Users\Public\Public Documents\Intuit\QuickBooks\Company Files\MyCompany.QBW",
                "MyCompany");

            connectionOpen = true;
            sessionManager.BeginSession("", ENOpenMode.omDontCare);
            sessionBegun = true;

            IMsgSetResponse responseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);

            sessionManager.EndSession();
            sessionBegun = false;
            sessionManager.CloseConnection();
            connectionOpen = false;

            WalkGeneralDetailReportQueryRs(responseMsgSet);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sessionBegun)
            {
                sessionManager.EndSession();
            }

            if (connectionOpen)
            {
                sessionManager.CloseConnection();
            }
        }
    }

    void BuildGeneralDetailReportQueryRq(IMsgSetRequest requestMsgSet)
    {
        IGeneralDetailReportQuery txQuery = requestMsgSet.AppendGeneralDetailReportQueryRq();
        txQuery.GeneralDetailReportType.SetValue(ENGeneralDetailReportType.gdrtTxnListByDate);
        txQuery.DisplayReport.SetValue(true);

        txQuery.ORReportPeriod.ReportPeriod.FromReportDate.SetValue(StartDate.Value);
        txQuery.ORReportPeriod.ReportPeriod.ToReportDate.SetValue(EndDate.Value);

    }

    void WalkGeneralDetailReportQueryRs(IMsgSetResponse responseMsgSet)
    {

        if (responseMsgSet == null) return;

        IResponseList responseList = responseMsgSet.ResponseList;
        if (responseList == null) return;

        //if we sent only one request, there is only one response, we'll walk the list for this sample
        for (int i = 0; i < responseList.Count; i++)
        {
            IResponse response = responseList.GetAt(i);
            //check the status code of the response, 0=ok, >0 is warning
            if (response.StatusCode >= 0)
            {
                //the request-specific response is in the details, make sure we have some
                if (response.Detail != null)
                {
                    //make sure the response is the type we're expecting
                    ENResponseType responseType = (ENResponseType) response.Type.GetValue();
                    if (responseType == ENResponseType.rtGeneralDetailReportQueryRs)
                    {
                        //upcast to more specific type here, this is safe because we checked with response.Type check above
                        IReportRet ReportRet = (IReportRet) response.Detail;
                        WalkReportRet(ReportRet);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }

    void WalkReportRet(IReportRet ReportRet)
    {
        if (ReportRet == null) return;
        if (ReportRet.ReportData != null)
        {
            if (ReportRet.ReportData.ORReportDataList != null)
            {
                for (int i35 = 0; i35 < ReportRet.ReportData.ORReportDataList.Count; i35++)
                {
                    IORReportData ORReportData = ReportRet.ReportData.ORReportDataList.GetAt(i35);
                    if (ORReportData.DataRow != null)
                    {
                        if (ORReportData.DataRow != null)
                        {
                            if (ORReportData.DataRow.RowData != null)
                            {
                            }

                            if (ORReportData.DataRow.ColDataList != null)
                            {
                                for (int i36 = 0; i36 < ORReportData.DataRow.ColDataList.Count; i36++)
                                {
                                    IColData ColData = ORReportData.DataRow.ColDataList.GetAt(i36);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (ORReportData.TextRow != null)
                    {
                        if (ORReportData.TextRow != null)
                        {
                        }
                    }

                    if (ORReportData.SubtotalRow != null)
                    {
                        if (ORReportData.SubtotalRow != null)
                        {
                            if (ORReportData.SubtotalRow.RowData != null)
                            {
                            }

                            if (ORReportData.SubtotalRow.ColDataList != null)
                            {
                                for (int i37 = 0; i37 < ORReportData.SubtotalRow.ColDataList.Count; i37++)
                                {
                                    IColData ColData = ORReportData.SubtotalRow.ColDataList.GetAt(i37);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (ORReportData.TotalRow != null)
                    {
                        if (ORReportData.TotalRow != null)
                        {
                            if (ORReportData.TotalRow.RowData != null)
                            {
                            }

                            if (ORReportData.TotalRow.ColDataList != null)
                            {
                                for (int i38 = 0; i38 < ORReportData.TotalRow.ColDataList.Count; i38++)
                                {
                                    IColData ColData = ORReportData.TotalRow.ColDataList.GetAt(i38);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I evaluate if the report results are null, and if they are not pass them into my AllItemsDataGrid.ItemSource?  Am I better off creating a TransactionQuery instead?

Comment: How are you filling the "transactions" that is passed on to AllItemsDataGrid.ItemSource?

Comment: My intent is to fill the transactions with report contents. Not sure how to restructure this.